# How to send data from one flutter app to another flutter app

Tags: flutter

i have a question,
How can one flutter app communicate with another flutter app locally, on the same house, say. I have made an app and now i want that app to send data to another app that i am planning on making. How can this be done when both apps are running on the same time?

**Thanks a lot**

Comment: are you build IOT apps? bluetooth, MQTT, maybe can be an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases, databases are frequently used. If you have your data from the first app stored on a database like Firebase(a No-SQL real-time database for flutter), you can have access to that data from another app.
For a better understanding of this, you can refer to this:
[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write)